# SQL Server : expand range to include missing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, ssms

I have a table (A) where the PK is an int:

```
Entry No.    Date     Product
-------------------------------
10001        1/1/19   Jeans
10002        1/1/19   Shoes
10003        2/1/19   Jeans...
```

I have another table (B) with sample data below (all values are int):

```
ID  Begin  End
-------------------
1   10001  10003
2   10004  10007
3   10008  10019...
```

I need to find the [ID] in table B for each [Entry No.] in table A.

I believe this requires unpivoting table B so [Begin] and [End] are in the same column then 'expanding' the rows so there's a row for every int:

```
ID  Entry No.
-------------
1   10001
1   10002
1   10003
2   10004
2   10005
2   10006
2   10007
3   10008...
```

I could then join this to Table A on [Table A].[Entry No.] = [Table B].[Entry.No.]

My unpivot code:

```
SELECT 
    ID, [Entry No.]
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM [Table B]) AS piv
UNPIVOT 
    ([Entry No.] FOR values IN (Begin, End)) AS unpvt
```

Is there a better way of doing this? If not, can you please help me with how to 'expand' table B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JOIN`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a join
     b
     on a.entry_no between b.begin_entry and b.end_entry
```